# Making JSON including JSONObject and JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I need to make a JSON like this on Android -

```
{"LoomMachine" : ["Waterjet","Rapier"],
"LoomType" : ["Dobby","Crank"]}
```

Any help on how to make this ?

Comment: Have you searched on **SO** or google before posting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for,

```
public Object JSONData() throws Exception {
    JSONObject JSONObjectData = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray loomMachineArr = new JSONArray();

    loomMachineArr.add("Waterjet");
    loomMachineArr.add("Rapier");

    JSONArray LoomType= new JSONArray();
    LoomType.add("Dobby");
    LoomType.add("Crank");

    JSONObjectData.put("LoomMachine", loomMachineArr);
    JSONObjectData.put("LoomType", LoomType);

    return root; 
}
```